# Google Cloud Speech2Text 404 response in spite API reference criteria is met

Tags: rest, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-text-to-speech, google-cloud-api-gateway

I'm still getting 404 after 24+ hours of double-checking that the request is in accordance with the API documentation. I'm using Postman.

This is the endpoint I'm trying to access:
https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/reference/rest/v1/text/synthesize

This is my request (cURL generated by Postman):

```
curl --location 'https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1/text:synthesize?key=API_KEY' \
--header 'X-Goog-Api-Key: API_KEY' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
  "input": {
    "text": "hi! how are you?" 
  },
  "voice": {
    "languageCode": "en-US",
    "name": "en-US-Neural2-F",
    "ssmlGender": "FEMALE"
  },
  "audioConfig": {
    "audioEncoding": "MP3",
    "speakingRate": 1.0,
    "pitch": 0.0,
    "volumeGainDb": 0.0
  }
}'
```

P.S. Cloud Text-to-Speech API product is enabled in my project.

P.P.S. 'API_KEY' above is a placeholder for my real API key.

P.P.P.S. The API key used is has these settings:

- Set an application restriction: *None*
- API restrictions: *Don't restrict key*

I tried the same request body within Google Cloud's APIs Explorer: API key enabled, Google OAuth 2.0 disabled. Somehow, within APIs Explorer I got the correct response, not 404. My request in postman still gets 404.